# Использование нескольких массивов

Tags: jquery, html

Доброго времени суток. Сразу оговорюсь, код не то чтобы не жизненный, но те тот, что в оригинале.
Html:

```
<div class="first">
    <div class="one">1</div>
    <div class="two">2</div>
    <div class="three">3</div>
</div>
<div class="first">
  <div class="one">2</div>
  <div class="two">3</div>
  <div class="three">4</div>
</div>
<div class="first">    
  <div class="one">3</div>
  <div class="two">4</div>
  <div class="three">5</div>
   </div>
```

Надо методами Jquery взять значения и вставить в переменную result так:
 `"one","two","three";"one","two","three";"one","two","three";`

Но при этом сколько будет дивов с классом "first", я не знаю, может, одна, две три или больше.

Comment: Классы будут заранее известны? Их всегда будет равное количество?

Comment: Имена классов не измены и известны их как раз три , количество блоков не известно может быть разным.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/diefair/tp4qa0Le/

Comment: Я очень извиняюсь, но я неправильно код код указал, сейчас внес изменения. В принципе ваш ответ правильный. Единственное, мне не значения классов, а html в самих дивах.

Comment: Тогда просто вместо attr('class') напишите html().